# How come npmjs website shows that Truffle latest version is 4.1.14, and that it was published 3 days ago?

Tags: truffle, solc, compilation

According to [this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle), Truffle latest version is 4.1.14, and it was published 3 days ago.

However:

1. I have been using this version for months now.
2. I have noticed this "published 3 days ago" several times before (more than 3 days ago).
3. This version works in conjunction with solc v0.4.24, and I have encountered several questions here about using Truffle in order to test contracts compiled with Solidity v0.5.0.

Can somebody please explain what exactly is going on here, and what is the current latest version of Truffle?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "3 days ago" is version agnostic: it just means the package, regardless of version, was last updated then.

If you look at the version history tab (the purple tab on the right):

```
Version History
5.0.0-next.18 ...... 3 days ago
5.0.0-beta.2  ..... 12 days ago
...
```

You'll also notice that the tagged `latest` version is `4.1.14`, whereas all `5.0` releases are tagged otherwise (e.g. `beta`):

```
Current Tags
4.1.14 ........... latest
5.0.0-beta.2 ..... beta
```

So the last stable release is `4.1.14`, but other beta releases have been made since then, hence the "3 days ago" thing.